# PHP Websites: Very high IOPS

Tags: linux, mysql, php, iops

We are hosting a set of websites on VM Cloud.
These sites were previously on a couple of dedicated servers but to enhance performance, we transferred them onto a Cloud environment.

The Cloud has SSD storage but they are now saying that we have very high IOPS and are goign to degrade us if we do not do anything soon.

We have good PHP Websites but they are run without any Caching.

how do I start to debug this?

Sincerely,

Khuram

**Edit**: We have two servers where one holds the code while the other holds the databases. But both of them are showing very high (~95%) writes.

Comment: Please tell more about the OS you're running, what kind of software it is running (webserver), what kind of operations you're doing in PHP (file operations, MySQL?) and what kind of virtualization this is (with container based virtualization you can't do as much of debugging as you can with hardware virtualization).

Comment: @gertvdijk The OS we are running is CentOS and the server is vcloud VM with 8GBRAM. The PHP websites are simple websites with regular reads and writes but here's the punch: IOPS reports tell that there is 95% writes and 5% reads and SSDs are hurting :-(

Comment: Stop writing so much?

Comment: Yes, I am also stumped by this. We never had such stats in the older dedicated setup.

Comment: 95% writes and 5% reads is very unusual for a website and typically those stats are reversed. What kind of websites (e.g. blog, ecommerce, etc) are you running that writes that much?

Comment: They are affiliate websites. Tell me, if a MySQL query has joins then does each of those count as a separate IOPS?

Comment: @Khuram A large amount of JOIN statements will cause more IOPS, but should not cause a 1:19 read/write ratio.

Have you checked your query cache settings in MySQL? Use `mytop` or `mtop` to watch the transactions on the database.

Comment: @nojak trying to install mytop but no package available in yum.

Comment: @Khuram You'll need to add the EPEL repository. Instructions on how to do that can be found [HERE](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-fedora-centos-linux-enable-epel-repo/).

Comment: @Khuram You can get `mtop` from the [RPMForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a very long shot, this could be related to the atime filesystem attribute. If your application consists of a lot of files, there is a good chance that the writes to the disk are simply updates to the access time of the files on the filesystem.

Try to remount the document root partition with the `noatime` mount option and see how it goes. You could use the following command:

```
mount -o remount,noatime /dev/sda2
```

Where `/dev/sda` is the disk partition containing your document root.

Comment: will this restart the whole system? I am not sure if I have the permission ( I am root but still its VM). We have a lot of production sites which I am uninclined to come in the way.

Comment: No, this doesn't require a reboot. It can be done online with no downtime.

Comment: And you have the permissions if you have root accces.

Comment: I would also suggest to change `remount,noatime` line to `remount,noatime,discard`. But it's only for ext4 partitions. And make sure that kernel version >=2.6.33

Comment: @melsayed its virtual setup so I do not see the partitions.
mount: can't find /dev/sda2 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab

Comment: Yes, sda2 is just an example. Run the `mount` command and provide it's output, please.

Comment: @melsayed here's the mount info: http://pastebin.com/MnQT52jc

Comment: Ok, try this:

    mount -o remount, noatime /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root

Comment: @melsayed mount: you must specify the filesystem type.
Also its a shared cloud, so I am a little hesitant

Comment: Try now, there was an additional space.

    mount -o remount,noatime /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root

Comment: @melsayed it ran without any print. What do I expect now? How do I check its working?

Comment: You should check and see if the IOPS report is still high..

Comment: It does not seem to have helped as I am now monitoring with nmon, top and iotop. Same 0% reads and 95%+ writes.